# .pop to remove items from lists causes weird problems with variable scopes in python

Tags: python, scope, pycharm, global-variables, shadowing

This one is making me absolutely crazy, so any help would be much appreciated.  I have a program where I'm iterating through a list in a function.  Here's a toy model of the problem:

```
masterList = ["person","woman","man","camera","television"]
workingList = masterList

def removeItem (workingList):
    item = workingList.pop(2)
    print("Test 1:",workingList)


removeItem(workingList)

print("Test 2:", workingList)
print("Test 3:", masterList)
```

As expected, "Test 1" prints out the list with an item removed.
However, "Test 2" also prints out the list with an item removed.  I wasn't expecting that, but no matter.  That's not the real problem, but I'm sure there's something I don't understand here about variable scopes and variable shadowing.

No the real problem is "Test 3", which as you can see, is printing out the **master**List, which shouldn't even be touched by the `removeItem` function or the `pop` function within it.  And yet, it too is printing out the list with an item removed.

How can this be happening, and how can I prevent it?

Thanks so much!

Cheers,
Ari

Answer (score 3):

**Python lists are mutable objects.**

```py
m = list([1, 2, 3])
n = m

a = 5
b = a

id(a) == id(b)
# id() return "identity" of the object.
# True,  Both a and b are references to the same object. 
id(m) == id(n)
# True,  Both m and n are references to the same object. 

b = b + 2 
id(a) == id(b)
# False, a new object on separate location is created, which b will point.

n.pop()
id(m) == id(n)
# True, the object is mutated, and m and n still references to the same object.
```

Since, python lists are mutable, m and n will still be reference to the same object after mutation. Whereas, for immutable objects like int, a new object will be created and the identifier will refer to the new object.

**Gist is, in your scenario, there has been only one object since python lists are mutable.**

However, if you need the original list unchanged when the new list is modified, you can use the copy() method.

`new_list = original_list.copy()`

The ids of `new_list` and `original_list` is different.

Learn here about mutability in detail: https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a copy of the `masterList`, otherwise `workingList` is nothing more than a reference.

If your `list` does not contain other containers (which yours doesn't), then a shallow copy is sufficient. There are numerous ways to make a shallow copy but `slicing` is the most optimal.

```
masterList = ["person","woman","man","camera","television"]
workingList = masterList[:] #copy via slice
```

**a bunch of other ways to make a shallow copy**

```
workingList = masterList * 1
workingList = masterList.copy()
workingList = list(masterList)
workingList = [*masterList]

import copy
workingList = copy.copy(masterList)
```

If you have a `list` that does possess something that holds a reference (like other containers, classes, etc), then you need to make a `deepcopy`.

```
import copy
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured it out.  The two lists are actually the same list unless you use `list.copy()`

So replacing the top two lines with:

```
masterList = ["person","woman","man","camera","television"]
workingList = masterList.copy()
```

makes everything perform as expected!  Well, I still can't say I understand how the variable scopes work in their entirety, but at least this solves the major problem.